# How do I send an integer value from service to a fragment?

Tags: android, android-service

I'm trying to get data from my Step counter service (i.e number of steps) to be displayed on a fragment. Here's my service:

```
public class StepCounterService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

SensorManager sensorManager;
boolean running = false;
static int initialStepCount = 0;
static int stepCount = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    sensorManager = (SensorManager) this.getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);

}

@Override
public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
    if (initialStepCount == 0) {
        initialStepCount = (int) event.values[0];
    }

    stepCount = (int)event.values[0] - initialStepCount;

    if (running) {
        // tv_steps.setText(String.valueOf(stepCount));
    }
}

@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {

}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

    running = true;
    Sensor countSensor = sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_STEP_COUNTER);
    if (countSensor != null) {
        sensorManager.registerListener(this, countSensor, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    } else {
    }
    return super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {

}
}
```

How do I send stepCount value to be displayed in my fragment on a TextView? What's the best way to do that?

Comment: use Broadcast receiver for that

Comment: @MD any tips on how to do that?

Comment: how do you want to call the fragment?
possible solution: you can set value to public static variable Or use Bundle

Comment: @MD  can I use Intent?

Comment: @EliasFazel I have a navigation drawer from which I call the fragment, I want the value when my MainActivity is launched so I can display it.

Answer (score 0):

To send data between a Service and other components, you could do a Bound Service; https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html This is Android's best way of communicating between components.

Answer (score 0):

There are few ways to do it:

1. Using `LocalBroadCastReceiver`.
2. Using [EventBus](https://github.com/greenrobot/EventBus). I prefer this way as it is much easier than the previous one with only a few lines of code:

   `EventBus.getDefault().post(new YourObjectWithANumber());`

Answer (score 0):

Probably, in your specific case, would be better to save and keep the number of steps on a file or in a database so that you can show it in your UI even when the app restarts